# New entrepreneur wondering how to introduce my multi-industry business

Tags: software-industry, software-development, business, entrepreneurship

After I graduated college I started a company developing SaaS (software). One year later and I have expanded my company to not only generate income from the SaaS licensing but also from developing mobile games, providing marketing services, SEO services, and I also produce and license music/audio, perform live music, and more.

When I get asked what I "do" I have a hard time succinctly explaining my job without either dragging or selling myself short.

Is there a name for a company that acts as sort of a jack of all trades, or operates in many industries?

I discovered "multi-industry" company, and "media company" but I still can't use either without explaining a whole lot either.

My question ultimately is: **Is there a word, industry/type of business, or a phrase that I can use to succinctly describe my job to someone I meet for the first time?**

This is the best (paraphrase) of what I usually say: I own a multi-industry business that, well, for all intents and purposes, does a lot of things. But, primarily I focus on SaaS because it brings the most revenue but I also offer marketing services and I write, record and perform music as an artist.

Comment: Depending on who you are talking to, do you ever put emphasis on specific parts of your company operations? In describing your work, some areas might be more relevant than others.

Comment: That's true. If I were at a specific networking event or otherwise appealing to someone in a certain industry I would definitely focus on whatever related field that might be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the companies.

I own X, a company that delivers SaaS and mobile games.

I also recently started Y for media services such as SEO, Marketing and Music.

Comment: Good idea I like that approach as well. Very helpful thank you

Answer (score 1):

> When I get asked what I "do" I have a hard time succinctly explaining my job without either dragging or selling myself short.

Assuming this is friends/family or acquaintances asking what you do. Why do you care if you sell yourself short. If your businesses are successful you'll have the results and proof to show that it's more than what you explain it as. Unless these people are clients or potential clients you shouldn't even waste your time.

On the other hand you could simply say

> I own a couple businesses, one relating to games and the other media services.

You shouldn't care what other people think, focus on your business and your results not what other people think/know.

Comment: Good advice! I think that's a good trait to have I'll try to focus more on that :)